# How to add single quotation around date in Excel for use in SQL?

Tags: sql, excel, quotes, quotation-marks

So I have a long list of dates that I need to add single quotations around.

However I cannot figure how to add the quotes around the date. I've looked up for help but most were using double quotations.

[image: Example:]

`8/13/2018` into  `'8/13/2018'`

Some Possible solutions I've found similar are

```
=TEXT(A1,"\""dd/mm/yyyy\""")
```

produces output: `"8/13/2018"`

However this only puts double quotations around the date.
The usual method I've been using on everything else is

```
="'"&8/13/2018&"'"
```

output: `'43325'`

But this does weird things with the date.

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone can show me how to add single quotation marks around a date in Excel.

Comment: `="'"&TEXT(c2, "dd/mm/yyyy")&"'"`

Comment: First if all, Excel date is the number of days past from 1900.01.01 as far as I remember. Thus it is a number. Anyway why can't xou add singlevquotes with TEXT?

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! Appreciate your help.

Comment: Yeah I didn't realize I need to turn the date into text format! What a great community to be in!

Comment: There may also be a special way to import the date to sql without converting it to a string.  I am not a sql user so I could be mistaken.

Comment: @ZorgoZ You should add it as an answer. Since it actually solved OP's problem

Comment: @forward-ed Yes it’s possible, but there’s no indication from OP that the Excel data will actually be queried from SQL. Perhaps just building the query itself which I do myself when too lazy to use regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

commenter was close but not 100%

```
="'" & TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy") & "'"
```

8/13/2018 is month day year not day month year

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
="'" & TEXT(A1,"dd-mmm-yy")
```

dd-mmm-yy can be formatted as needed ex. mm/dd/yyyy etc...

[image: excel column screenshot]